# What is the canonical implementation of System F?

Tags: types, lambda-calculus, system-f, typed-lambda-calculus

[System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) is a great way to simply reason about types when programming a prototype. Other than implementing it myself, I'd like to use an existing implementation.

When looking for implementations, there doesn't seem to be any - and I'm not sure why.

My question is: **What is the canonical implementation of System F?**

Comment: I'm not sure about "canonicity", but you can have a look at the implementations (in OCaml) by B.C. Pierce [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/fullpoly/) and [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/fullomega). The implementations are described in his [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) book.

Comment: Cool - can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: All right -- it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/main.html) book by B.C. Pierce is famous (among other things) for providing and discussing [implementations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers) of typed lambda calculi in OCaml.

The book provides an implementation of System F, called [`fullpoly`](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/fullpoly/) and explains the implementation details in Chapter 25. `fullpoly` extends an implementation of [simply-typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) lambda calculus with booleans -- [`simplebool`](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/simplebool).

The instructions for building and executing those typecheckers and interpreters can be found [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/resources.html#checkers).